# Doing a screen capture in Chrome of all DIVs under element using getDisplayMedia

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, screen-capture

Is there a way to take a screenshot of a HTML element and all its children using:  getDisplayMedia and save it / download it as a single png image?

I do not want to stream content, I just have a very complex SVG / Canvas / HTML setup and need to take a screenshot of the entire root DIV.
Tried many of the techniques for image snapshot in Chrome but non of them did the trick in capturing everything, so I am thinking maybe MediaRecorder > png will work?

thanks you

Answer (score 4):

If your element fits entirely in the viewport, I'd recommend the recent [Region Capture API](https://github.com/w3c/mediacapture-region/#summary) that landed in Chrome.

See https://developer.chrome.com/docs/web-platform/region-capture/ for more details.

```js
const mainContentArea = document.querySelector("#mainContentArea");
const cropTarget = await CropTarget.fromElement(mainContentArea);

// Prompt user to share the tab's content.
const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({ preferCurrentTab: true });
const [track] = stream.getVideoTracks();

// Start cropping the self-capture video track using the CropTarget <-- Magic!
await track.cropTo(cropTarget);

const canvas = drawToCanvas(stream);
canvas.toBlob((blob) => {
  // See https://web.dev/patterns/files/save-a-file/ to save this blob locally.
});

/* Utils */

async function drawToCanvas(stream) {
  const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  const video = document.createElement("video");
  video.srcObject = stream;

  // Play it.
  await video.play();

  // Draw one video frame to canvas.
  canvas.width = video.videoWidth;
  canvas.height = video.videoHeight;
  canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(video, 0, 0);

  return canvas;
}
```

In the future, you may be able to use the Element Capture Web API. See the current proposal: https://github.com/WICG/proposals/issues/73

Comment: You're using await inside of a synchronous function here